# Thymeleaf dropdown list + bootstrap

Tags: java, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

In my app I have a thymeleaf dropdown list using enum values.

I want to connect it with bootstrap to give it a better aspect, I was trying to do it by myself, and have tried to find some help on the internet, but still nothing.

My dropdown List:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<form th:object="${money}" th:action="@{saveOperation}" action="#" method="post">

    <select th:field="*{name}">

        <option th:each=" value : ${T(com.bartosz.kolej.whereismymoney.operations.model.MoneyOperations.OperationsNames).value()}"
                th:value="${value}"
                th:text="${value.getDisplayName()}">
        </option>

    </select>
    <input type="number" required th:field="*{value}" class="form-controll" placeholder="value" step="0.01  "/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" th:value="Save"/>

</form>
```

and i want insert it in code like this:

```
<div class="dropdown show">
<a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<div class="dropdown show">
<a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Category
</a>

<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <div th:each="c:${categories}">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" th:text="${c.getCategoryName()}">Action</a>
    </div>
</div>
```